# Variable changes its value

Tags: c++, class, opengl

I have a very strange problem with variables. After few calls in OPENGL render loop one variable changes its value (`verticesSize`) without any reasons while the 2nd variable(verticesSize2) not...
For contrary When I loop them (using for) in any other place of the program both keeps the correct value.
It doesn't matter how I name 1st variable it always changes its value so it must be memory problem however I don't know what can cause it. Any ideas?

cpp. file

```
void CosmicBody::InitShape(unsigned int uiStacks, unsigned int uiSlices, float    fA,       float fB, float fC)
{
float tStep = (Pi) / (float)uiSlices;
float sStep = (Pi) / (float)uiStacks;

float SlicesCount=(Pi+0.0001)/tStep;
float StackCount=(2*Pi+0.0001)/sStep;
this->verticesSize=((int) (SlicesCount+1) * (int) (StackCount+1))*2;
    this->verticesSize2=((int) (SlicesCount+1) * (int) (StackCount+1))*2;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include ....
CosmicBody one;

void renderScene(void)
{

std::cout<<one.verticesSize<<endl;
std::cout<<one.verticesSize2<<endl;

fps.calculateFPS(clock.elapsedTime);

glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

**EDIT**
OK I found which line cause the problem
in this function function `sprintf` makes the program to run incorrect.Why function of another class cause this?
     void FpsCalc::calculateFPS(unsigned int currentTime)
     {

```
frameCount++;
int timeInterval = currentTime - previousTime;

if(timeInterval > 1000)
{
    float fps = frameCount / (timeInterval / 1000.0f);
    previousTime = currentTime;
    frameCount = 0;
    sprintf(this->fps,"%f",fps); //this line makes mess 
}
```

}

```
#ifndef FPSCALC_H
#define FPSCALC_H
class FpsCalc
{
private:
int frameCount;
float previousTime;


public:
FpsCalc();
void calculateFPS(unsigned int currentTime);
char fps[5];

~FpsCalc(){};
};
#endif
```

Comment: Its _too much_ code. Why do you show this part, but omit some `...Opengl stuff..` and `p1` definition? Usually memory problems connected with pointers, but you havn't show any.

Comment: First of all - bad idea to have empty `CosmicBody` constructor, it shall initialize `verticesSize` and `verticesSize2` because otherwise they can contain garbage. Second, use single-step debugging to localize the line causing problems, your code here is not enough to detect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fps` buffer is not large enough to hold the resulting output, resulting in undefined behaviour:

```
sprintf(this->fps,"%f",fps);
```

I am unsure of the default precision but on my machine:

```
float f = 1.1f;
```

produces:

```
1.100000
```

which is 9 characters (7 digits, period and null terminator).

You need to specify the precision:

```
sprintf(this->fps, "%.2f", fps);
```

or as this is C++ use a `std::ostringstream` and `std::string` instead.

```
std::string fps;

...

float fps = frameCount / (timeInterval / 1000.0f);
std::ostringstream s;
s << fps;
this->fps = s.str();
```